# Write-Host "" - Alternative

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there an alternative to : Write-Host "" to return carriage in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe also a option:

```
Write-Host "Line1"
"" #Line2
Write-Host "Line3"
```

Answer (score 4):

Other options:

```
 write-host

 $host.UI.WriteLine()

 [console]::WriteLine() # this also  in ISE v3.0
```

Inside a string:

```
"Firts line`r`n`r`nThird Line"
```